# MVC5: Error when adding namespace to web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in my view:

```
@model IEnumerable<MusicStore.Models.Album>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

<h2>Search Results</h2>...
```

I don't want to be using the fully qualified class name, so I want to use this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Album>
```

And then I added this entry in the view's web.config:

```
<add namespace="MusicStore.Models"/>
```

But I still get this error:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Album' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you are adding it to the correct web.config? This should go in the web.config file in the views folder and not in the top level project folder

Comment: Hi @KnightFox , Yes it's in the view's web.config

Comment: What's the full namespace of the `Album` class?  The view `@model` may not need a common namespace prefix, but the view web.config will.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding

```
@using MusicStore.Models
@model IEnumerable<Album>
```

to the top of your view?

Comment: Hi Casey, it works in the view, but I would like to add the namespace reference for all views in the view's web config file

Comment: Have you tried restarting visual studio to see if it picked up the changes?